# How can I draw on two side by side inkcanvases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have two inkCanvas elements in WPF displayed side by side. I want to be able to draw lines seamlessly from one inkCanvas to the next. Right now the stroke gets clipped at the boundary and you have to release the mouse and press it again on the next canvas to continue the line.

I also read that inkCanvas wasn't really the way to go for drawing. It was more for simple things like signatures. What are you supposed to use instead?

Comment: Why side by side and not just one?

Comment: because I want to be able to add tiles (inkCanvas) in all kinds of directions and then save each tile as a separate image. I figure this solution doesn't require much processing when saving or when adding a new tile.

Comment: Premature optimization alert! Are you absolutely sure that performance is actually an issue?

Comment: Yes I think it is. I don't know about premature optimization, I usually optimise at the design stage so that I don't have to optimise later, which I feel is much harder and usually less effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try with one inkcancas:

- add tiles by replacing the current inkcanvas with a bigger one and copying the strokes
- it might work
- if it doesn't you will know what you need more

Yes inkcanvas is for simple things but before you start coding a lot try to specify what you need.

Comment: I want to make a fairly complex drawing program

Comment: Then don't use the inkcanvas as it only supports strokes. Use a canvas and add an inkcanvas on top when you need to support strokes.